# Nancy Model Binding to subclass. Autodetection?

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

I'm wondering if I can get Nancy to auto bind a request to a subclass of the type I specify in the type parameters. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Given these classes:

```
public class Shape
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}

public class Triangle : Shape
{
    public string SomeTriangleOnlyProp { get; set; }
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public string SomeSquareOnlyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Then given this Json:

```
{
    "Height" : 10,
    "Width" : 20
}
```

Then this is my desired result:

```
var shape = this.Bind<Shape>(); //Returns a Shape object
```

Given this Json:

```
{
    "Height" : 10,
    "Width" : 20,
    "SomeTriangleOnlyProp" : "Triangle"
}
```

Then this is my desired result:

```
var shape = this.Bind<Shape>(); //Returns a Triangle object
```

Given this Json:

```
{
    "Height" : 10,
    "Width" : 20,
    "SomeSquareOnlyProp" : "Square"
}
```

Then this is my desired result:

```
var shape = this.Bind<Shape>(); //Returns a Square object
```

Could I only achieve this with a custom binding class? I could try to bind to each type separately and handle any errors but that seems really unoptimal.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, I'm not sure if it's the best one but it's working how I need it so it's what I'll go with for now. I've written a custom model binder that looks at the json to try and determine what object it should serialize to:

```
public class ShapeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object Bind(NancyContext context, Type modelType, object instance, BindingConfig configuration, params string[] blackList)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
        {
            var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (json.Contains("SomeTriangleOnlyProp"))
            {
                var triangle = new Nancy.Json.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Triangle>(json);
                return triangle;
            }
            else if (json.Contains("SomeSquareOnlyProp"))
            {
                var square = new Nancy.Json.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Square>(json);
                return square;
            }
            else
            {
                var shape = new Nancy.Json.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Shape>(json);
                return shape;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanBind(Type modelType)
    {
        return modelType == typeof(Shape);
    }
}
```

Calling this in the `NancyModule` with `var shape = this.Bind<Shape>();` returns a `Triangle` if the JSON had the triangle prop, a `Square` if the JSON had the square prop, or just the regular base `Shape` class if the JSON had neither.